# Are the values in square brackets the defaults?

Tags: postgresql, psql

[image]

If I just press 'enter' through all these prompts without entering anything, is it going to default to the server localhost, the database postgres, and port 5432? Does entering values overwrite the default fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes they are the defaults for postgres

Comment: I think you answer part of the question. You should [edit] your answer and include a source or proof of what you are saying to make it stronger. A single sentence doesn't really feel like a good answer. Explaining the second part of the question would also help.